# How do I mv or cp a *.u1conflict file

Tags: ubuntu-one, rename

Ubuntu One is putting files in conflict while I'm working on them. The original file is gone and only the conflict file remains. To make matters worse, I can't mv, cp the file to the original name. If I delete the conflict file I'm unable to create a new file with the original name.

How do I rename the file, and how do I prevent U1 from messing with my files that are in use?

Comment: When you say you can't rename or copy the `.u1conflict` file, what actually happens when you try?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am voting to close it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards.

Answer (score -1):

Just change to the directory of the file and rename it to the original name without the .u1conflict extension.

or

If that doesn't work, turn off ubuntu one sync then change it.

Moving the file should be easy enough.

Comment: The ubuntuone sync daemon runs with ordinary user privileges, so it shouldn't do anything that requires superuser privileges to fix.  I think we need more information to tell what the problem is.